# Branch cut of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I try to understand what branch cut I have for a certain complex function:

$$\begin{align}
 \lambda(L,k)= \sqrt{k^2+i\frac{x}{L}}
\end{align} $$
where $k, L$ are complex numbers and $x\in \mathbb{R}_+$ constant.
Now I am note sure where this function is defined. I know that the branch cut for the complex root function
$$\sqrt{\cdot}\colon \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0)\to \mathbb{C}, z\to \sqrt{z} $$
is $(-\infty,0)$, but in my case i am confused to have 2 different complex values and I think the branch cut must be somewhat shifted...(?)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If it matters, your function $\lambda$ is a function of two complex variables, not one, so "branch cut" does not have exactly the same meaning as for functions of one variable. (The domain is not a subset of $\mathbf{C}$, but of $\mathbf{C}^{2}$.) Still, your function is defined where the radicand $k^{2} + ix/L$ is not negative real.

Comment: To make it easier I want to let $L$ be real and very small. Then for every $K$ there ex. an $\epsilon>0$, s.t. for 
$$\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}\subset\left(B_K(0)\times \left(-\epsilon,\epsilon \right)  \right) $$
the func is welldefined. Since for very small values of $L$ the $i\frac{a}{L}$ becomes really big and with big values for $i\frac{a}{L}$ also the imaginary part of $k^2$ must be  big for the radicant to become negative real. I think that if I bound the values for $k$ in a ball with radius $K$, I always find a $\epsilon$ small enough, s.t. the func. doesn't become negative real?